# how to receive and then send rabbitmq message spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I followed Rabbitmq tutorial for java Spring boot here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-spring-amqp.html

My goal here is to receive string variable from one microservice in Spring using rabbitmq, append string to that value  and pass the result to API server. So I have to combine sender and receiver code in one class file.

Receiving queue is python_java and sending queue is java_api.

My code
**Ampqtutorials application.java**

```
package com.example.amqp.tutorials.amqptutorials;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class AmqpTutorialsApplication {

    @Profile("usage_message")
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner usage() {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {

            @Override
            public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("This app uses Spring Profiles control its behavior.\n");
                System.out.println("Sample usage: java -jar rabbit-tutorials.jar --spring.profiles.active=hello-world,sender");
            }
        };
    }

    @Profile("!usage_message")
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner tutorial() {
        return new RabbitAmqpTutorialsRunner();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AmqpTutorialsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**RabbitAmqpTutorialsRunner.java**

```
package com.example.amqp.tutorials.amqptutorials;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

public class RabbitAmqpTutorialsRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${tutorial.client.duration:0}")
    private int duration;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Ready ... running for " + duration + "ms");
        Thread.sleep(duration);
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

**Tut1Config.java**

```
package com.example.amqp.tutorials.amqptutorials.tut1;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Profile({"tut1","hello-world"})
@Configuration
public class Tut1Config {

    @Bean
    public Queue hello() {
        return new Queue("python_java");
    }

    @Profile("receiver")
    @Bean
    public Tut1Receiver receiver() {
        return new Tut1Receiver();
    }

    @Profile("sender")
    @Bean
    public Tut1Sender sender() {
        return new Tut1Sender();
    }
}
```

**Tut1Sender.java**

```
package com.example.amqp.tutorials.amqptutorials.tut1;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

public class Tut1Sender {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 500)
    public void send() {
        String message = "Hello World!";
        this.template.convertAndSend("java_api", message);
        System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "'");
    }
}
```

**Tut1Receiver.java**

```
package com.example.amqp.tutorials.amqptutorials.tut1;

import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitHandler;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;

@RabbitListener(queues = "python_java")
public class Tut1Receiver {

    @RabbitHandler
    public void receive(String in) {
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + in + "'");
    }
}
```

So how do I put receiving and sending functionality in same file ?